# jQuery - Selecting a parent that has a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have a Div which may contain an INPUT with a class of "datepicker"

```
<div class="rereg-input180">
     ... some layers
         <input class="one two datepicker three">
               ....
```

I need to apply a Style="clear" to the top div. However I don't want to if that div doesn't contain a datepicker child.

How do I select it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/has/ this will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do:

```
$('.datepicker').closest('.rereg-input180').addClass('clear');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this -

```
$div = $('.rereg-input180');

if($div.find('.datepicker').length){
  // apply style
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .has()  http://api.jquery.com/has/ assuming you want the clear both, if it's a clear class, the you can just .addClass() instead of .css()

```
$('.rereg-input180').has('.datepicker').css('clear', 'both');
```

if you want to be more specific you can do

```
$('.rereg-input180').has('input.datepicker').css('clear', 'both');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector:

```
$('div.rereg-input180:has(:text.datepicker)').css('clear', 'both')
```

Comment: Very interesting @Huangism didn't knew that!

Comment: Yea I was in your position a few days ago and thought the :has is better but apparently not lol

Comment: At least it's faster than .has() LOL

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying or what you read from the jsperf link. But .has() runs faster as the tests shows in that link

Comment: The blue bars are the .has() and it clearly shows it is greater than the red bars. Only in legacy IE the red is a bit faster than blue

Comment: I've ran the tests into my browser, I didn't realized that. I'm using FF22 and the .has filter is 29% slower than :has selector.
That's why I said that, but it is wrong. You're right.

Comment: not a big deal as long as the community uses the efficient one

Answer (score 0):

You could use: [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) `.parent()`

`$(".datepicker").parent().css("clear","both");`